# Adding the middle elements in an array without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix like this:

```
B = array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
           [7, 7, 8, 9, 9]])
```

I want to be able to get this result:

```
result = np.array([[1, 4, 6, 8, 3],
                   [4, 13, 15, 17, 6],
                   [7, 22, 24, 26, 9]])
```

I am keep the first element and the last element in each row, but added the first 3 elements to get what in the middle.

I have a code for that using a loop, which is below using a loops.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(1,4):
        C[i,j] = np.sum(B[i,j-1:j+2])
    C[i][0] = B[i][0]
    C[i][-1] = B[i][-1]
```

but I want an optimized way without loops. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Compute a 2D convolution with [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and a 1x3 kernel:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

B[:, 1:-1] = convolve2d(B, np.ones((1, 3), dtype=B.dtype), mode='valid')
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  6,  8,  3],
       [ 4, 13, 15, 17,  6],
       [ 7, 22, 24, 26,  9]])
```

Comment: @Iphy Kelvin: if this answer was useful you might click on left the OK-button, so the sponsor of the answer for you will get a feedback and some credits.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops.

```
C[:,[0,4]] = B[:,[0,4]]
C[:,1] = B[:,0]+B[:,1]+B[:,2]
C[:,2] = B[:,1]+B[:,2]+B[:,3]
C[:,3] = B[:,2]+B[:,3]+B[:,4]
```

Comment: Thanks, the example I gave is an easy trial one. The matrix I have is huge. I can't do that for all the rows unfortunately.

Comment: OK, the convolution is a better answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could add sub-matrices using subscript assignments.  This would work for rolling sums of 3 on any size matrix:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
              [4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
              [7, 7, 8, 9, 9]])

result = B.copy()
result[:,1:-1] += B[:,:-2] + B[:,2:]

print(result)

[[ 1  4  6  8  3]
 [ 4 13 15 17  6]
 [ 7 22 24 26  9]]
```

This could be generalized to any (odd) window size using a difference of cumsum for the additions:

```
w = 3
m = w//2
C        = B.cumsum(axis=1)
C[:,w:] -= C[:,:-w]
result   = B.copy()
result[:,m:m-w+1] = C[:,w-1:]

print(result)

[[ 1  4  6  8  3]
 [ 4 13 15 17  6]
 [ 7 22 24 26  9]]
```